# Performing supervised classification on old aerial imagery taken in 1950s

Tags: qgis, scp, historical-imagery

I am working on a project to track the expansion of the city's built area in the last 70-80 years, and I have to deal with scanned images taken before satellites were first used, and I can't seem to find any resources on how I can do any sort of pixel classification on them.

I am not an expert and I'm still learning.

Comment: Geocorrection and Photogrammetry  is a good guide for older aerial photography https://www.rgs.org/CMSPages/GetFile.aspx?nodeguid=a2bb62c1-654b-443b-b62e-0476af69aef0&lang=en-GB (if you have stereo pairs even better)